# Pygame dice to be completely random

Tags: python, pygame, dice

So I made a button in pygame that every time I click it, it gives me a random number 1-6, as a dice should. However, it keeps giving me the same number as many times I press the button unless I close the window and run the program again. Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
import random
pygame.init()

def main():
    screen= pygame.display.set_mode([550,200])
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.set_caption('dice')
    pygame.display.flip()

    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)


    label = myfont.render("click the button to roll the dice!", 2, (255,0,255))
    screen.blit(label, (200, 100))



    dice= [1,2,3,4,5,6]

    button= pygame.Rect(100,100,50,50)
    playerroll= random.choice(dice)

    running= True

    while running:
         for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running= False



            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                if button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    print("you rolled a:" , playerroll)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255,255,255], button)
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Can anyone help me with my problem ? Thanks

Comment: remove the `playerroll` definition and replace `print("you rolled a:" , playerroll)` with `print("you rolled a:" , random.choice(dice))`

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 4):

`playerroll` is (randomly) chosen before the main loop - And not when you click the button! You should update it after the mouseclick, i.e.

```
if button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
    print("you rolled a:" , random.choice(dice))
```

Comment: when i do that now it just keeps printing numbers for however long i hold the button down

Comment: Do you still have `if button.collidepoint(mousepos):` at the same level of indentation as in the original code? If so, it should have the same result (except for being random correctly)

Comment: yeah i have it at the same indentation level in my code and the above

Comment: @groot are you sure you use `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` ? Maybe you use  `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` which works different and you can get your problem. Or maybe it is problem only on your system - do you use Windows/Linux/MacOS ?

Comment: and yeah i use MOUSEBUTTONDOWN

Comment: I've just tested it on my machine... It's working exactly as it's supposed to. Did your code keep on printing (the same) numbers before changing? Could you perhaps add the changed code to your original post?

Comment: yeah i can change it back to the original and it kept printing the same thing before changing

Comment: Strange... I copied your exact code and it worked fine for me (python 2.7, windows 7). The only thing I could imagine is that it's either something on your particular machine, or on your mouse triggering constant mouse down events.